# Saving Python Numpy Structure As MySQL Blob

Tags: python, mysql, numpy

One of my programs creates a very large numpty array that I wish to save as a Blob within a database as accessing the array is far faster than going back to the previous level and creating it. I can add it to the database by saving an .npz file to disc using:-

```
import numpy as n
n.savez(outfile,**kwargs)
```

and saving this file to the database with:-

```
myData = open(outfile, 'rb').read()
sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (BlobColumn) VALUES (%s)"
cursor.execute(sql, (myData,))
```

Whilst this works it seems somewhat inelegant but I cannot figure out how to save it directly to the database?

Comment: Also, should `numpty` be `numpy` ?

Comment: @Paul - obviously a typo on my part and amended. I checked the code base and we have no "numpty"s!

Comment: Is this impossible then?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite some time later - I was able to do this using pandas `pd.to_sql`. Say I have some numpy array `x` that I want to insert as a blob column. Then you can do the following:

```
row = [x.dumps()]
data = pd.DataFrame(row, columns = ['myBlob'])
data.to_sql(name = "myTable", schema = "mySchema", con = dbConnection, if_exists = "append", index = False)
```

This should place the blob in the mySchema.myTable with some `cnumpy.core.multiarray` ... data type.